# How to get a linear array when indexing 3rd or higher dimensions in multidimensional arrays

Tags: matlab

Consider having the following multidimensional array:

A = [1 2;3 4];
B = [5 6;7 8];
C = cat(3, A, B);

Well it is like a cube, I want to slice the first row, slice the first column and that's it.
When I do:

```
C(1,1,:)
```

I get two separate answers:

```
C(1,1,1) = 1
C(1,1,2) = 5
```

And if I do

```
D = C(1,1,:)
```

I get D to be a multidimensional.

I want this

```
D = [1 5];
```

That's it, how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `squeeze()` function to drop the extra dimensions:

```
>> squeeze(C(1,1,:))'

ans =

     1     5
```